# how to get text present between html tags like <div>text</div> using selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

how to get text-'True' present between html tags `<div>text</div>` using `selenium` `C#`.

```
<div type='data' id='OfferInCart' style='display:none;'>True</div>
```

I have tried to get it using :

```
string status = OfferIncart.GetAttribute("text");
```

and also with :

```
string status = OfferIncart.GetAttribute("div");
```

but not getting the text. I even using `javascript` with below code :

```
string status = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", OfferIncart);
```

still my code is not working.

Want to check for the value whether `TRUE/False` of above line of code using `C#` `Selenium`. Please suggest

Comment: Can you show us your efforts/code?

Comment: Please find my code and i have tried  to get it using                              string status = OfferIncart.GetAttribute("text");   and also with                 string status = OfferIncart.GetAttribute("div");                                                    but not getting the text

Comment: Please use javascript for this

Comment: I even using javascript with below code:                                                                                               string status = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)browser).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", OfferIncart);                                                still my code is not working :(

Comment: show your `OfferIncart` code means how to find and store element in this variable

Comment: and did you tried `OfferIncart.Text` to getting text of the element??

Answer (score 1):

Selenium provides [`.Text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm) property to getting the `innerText` of the `IWebElement`, without any leading or trailing whitespace, and with other whitespace collapsed. So you should try using `IWebElement.Text` as below :-

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("OfferInCart"));
string status = element.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `xpath` to get the same.

```
//div[@type='data' and @id='OfferInCart']
```

Answer (score 0):

`IWebElement.Text;` did not work for me. I found a solution in Java and tried applying that. It worked. For people who are lately looking for solution hope this may help and below is the code.

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("OfferInCart"));
string status = element.GetAttribute("innerText");
```